# What are the Ubuntu 13.04 32-bit desktop system requirements?

Tags: 13.04, system-requirements

The Ubuntu 13.04 32-bit desktop system requirements. What are they?

Comment: I don't remember being asked to install 32-bits components on my 64-bits architectures. When are you prompted this ?

Comment: Tell us about your hardware (computer model/manufacturer) and we'll  tell you if it can run Ubuntu (and possibly more). Otherwise you can read the Wikipedia article about Ubuntu or [SystemRequirements](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements). (I really consider you should detail your question a little bit more, since this is a basic Google-answerable question.)

Comment: Possible Doubite: 311991

Answer (score 3):

**Minimum System Requirements  (OUTDATED)**

- 300 MHz x86 processor
- 64 MB of system memory (RAM)
- At least 4 GB of disk space (for full installation and swap space)
- VGA graphics card
- capable of 640x480 resolution

  CD-ROM drive

---

**Recommended Minimum System Requirements**

- 700 MHz processor (about Intel Celeron or better)
- 512 MiB RAM (system memory)
- 5 GB of hard-drive space (or USB stick, memory card or external drive
  but see LiveCD for an alternative approach)
- VGA capable of 1024x768 screen resolution

---

**Recommended System Requirements  (OUTDATED)**

- 1.2 GHz x86 processor
- 256 MB of system memory (RAM)
- 8 GB of disk space

---

**NOTES**

I am trying to look up a non outdated version!

---

**Sources**

> http://forum.freeeducation365.info/Thread-system-requirements-for-ubuntu-linux-13-04-versioin
>
> http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-desktop-latest
>
> https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements

(Outdated)  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements/GutsyGibbon